# Can "X is enough." be used when X is plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjugation

I was writing a [meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10824/1719) on another site where saying "Done." was a sufficient post. In order to meet the character limit, I typed the sentence:

> Sometimes five characters is really enough.

After looking at it, I changed it to:

> Sometimes five characters **are** really enough.

Somehow, as a native speaker, the first one still *feels* better to me, although I can't figure out why that is or if my feeling is misleading me.

Is my initial pass on the sentence grammatically correct? Does it mean something different than the second take?

Comment: I would go for "is really enough" though I can't explain why either.

Comment: @Centaurus: I think the reason for your preference (which I share) is that we're not so much thinking about the inherently plural subject *five [different] characters* - rather, it's a matter of *that amount, that number* (a *single* value, one of many possible alternatives).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is specifically about the case where the form is "X and Y is/are enough". This question is about a count situation.

Comment: @Barmar: A ***and*** B (or 1 **+** 1) - it (not *they* :) is still just a matter of *ambiguous plurality*.

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes five characters is really enough.
>   Sometimes five characters are really enough.

Here's how I see it:

Five characters is good. ---> a group of five letters is good.

Five characters are good. ---> individually, five characters are all good.